# opencv assertion failed error-438 while computing HOG features

Tags: c++, opencv

I use Hog features in character recognition problem .By using compute function in Hog descriptor class in OpenCV. I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((n & (n - 1)) == 0) in cv::alignSize, file C:\opencv-3.2.0\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/utility.hpp, line 438
```

here is the code,there is no build errors. this code has already run in my system but could not run in another system. that system shows above error during running

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "databasereader.h"
#include "tinydir.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
     DatabaseReader dr;

    dr.readTrainingFiles();

    std::vector<int> labels= dr.getTrainLabels();
    std::vector<std::string>trainingFileNames = dr.getTrainFileNames();

    Mat trainingData;
    std::vector<int>trainingLabels;
    Mat img_gray;
    Size newSize(20,20);

    cout << "size =" << trainingFileNames.size()<<endl;

    for(unsigned int index=0;index<trainingFileNames.size();index++)
    {
        cout<<"file  "<<labels[index]<<"  "<<trainingFileNames[index]<<endl;
        Mat img=imread(trainingFileNames[index]);

        resize(img, img, newSize);
        imshow("india",img);

        cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        HOGDescriptor hog(
                    Size(20,20), //winSize
                    Size(10,10), //blocksize
                    Size(5,5), //blockStride,
                    Size(10,10), //cellSize,
                    9, //nbins,
                    1, //derivAper,
                    -1, //winSigma,
                    0, //histogramNormType,
                    0.2, //L2HysThresh,
                    1,//gammal correction,
                    64,//nlevels=64
                    1);//Use signed gradients

        vector<float>  descriptor;
        hog.compute(img_gray,descriptor);

        Mat vec(descriptor);
        vec = vec.reshape(0,1);
        //vector of images
        trainingData.push_back(vec);
        trainingLabels.push_back(labels[index]);
    }
    //convertion
    trainingData.convertTo(trainingData,CV_32FC1);
    cout<<"training started"<<endl;

    Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm= cv::ml::SVM::create();
    svm->setType(cv::ml::SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(cv::ml::SVM::POLY);
    svm->setTermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER,100, 1e-6));
    svm->setGamma(3);
    svm->setDegree(2);
    svm->setC(100);
    svm->train(trainingData,cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE,trainingLabels);
    svm->save("classifier.xml");
    cout<<"training completed"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion you are getting is normal, I don't know how you are not getting it on other system (maybe parameters are different on other system).

`HOGDescriptor::compute` internally use `alignSize(size_t sz, int n)` function which has an assertion in it's body :

```
assert((n & (n - 1)) == 0); // n is a power of 2
```

This assertion state that input **must** be a number of the power of 2. This applies to cell and block size (which are 10 and 10 in your code) as far as I know. So to get rid of this assertion you need to change them to 8 or any number of power of 2 (i.e 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...).

Comment: i changed my code as you said 16,16 block size,16,16 cell size, 4,4 stride